# blur fires before data bind angular 4 firefox

Tags: angular, firefox

I have a bit of angular that provides a date to a function on blur. In Chrome(v62) it works normally but doesn't appear to work with Firefox (57).

//html

```
<input #expirationDate type="date"  max="2999-12-31" class="form-control" name="ChargeExpirationDate" [ngModel]="charge.ExpirationDate" (blur)="editCharge(charge, 'ExpirationDate', expirationDate.value)"/>
```

//TS component

```
editCharge(charge: object, property: string, newValue: any): void {
  console.log(newValue);
  console.log(charge);
  //other stuff
  charge[property] = newValue;
}
```

If you key in a date and the input loses focus

- In Chrome: the function is called and the `newValue` contains a date string.
- In Firefox: the function fires but the `newValue` is set to `""`. Even more strangely, the result of `console.log(charge);` will actually contain the string but only if observed after the `editCharge` function completes.

Is there a way to get `newValue` to be set correctly before the blur event in Firefox? I didn't want to use `ngModelChange` because of some unusual behavior we noticed when we tried to key in dates in Chrome with it.

Comment: try `focusout` event

Comment: That seems to have solved it thank you! will there be any consequences with the fact that it [doesn't bubble](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusout)? It's not completely clear to me what that means.

Comment: which part is not clear? please elaborate

Comment: Never mind. I was a little concerned about this comment from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusout) : 
 ".... The main difference between this event and blur is that the latter doesn't bubble." 
But I looked it up and I don't think it will negatively impact my application.

Comment: so your query is solved right?

Comment: yes it is solved

Comment: @Thank you happy yo help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comment, you should be using `focusout` event instead of `blur`

```
<input #expirationDate type="date"  
        class="form-control"
        max="2999-12-31"
        name="ChargeExpirationDate"
        [ngModel]="charge.ExpirationDate" 
        (focusout)="editCharge(charge, 'ExpirationDate', expirationDate.value)"/>
```